# Tomcat context path issue

Tags: java, tomcat

I deployed application in tomcat under webapps/testing1 folder.

http://localhost:8080/testing1/index.html

This html page has anchor tag with href as "/login"

When I click on anchor, it takes to localhost:8080/login instead of localhost:8080/testing1/login

I did not do any change in tomcat conf xmls. How can I make all paths starts with slash would goto application context?

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: what framework you using? spring? jersey?

Comment: Simple java web application. Just a web.XML + login servlet + index.html only.

Comment: You're not exactly clear about what you can and can't do. Just making it a relative path (link to 'login' instead of '/login') instantly solves this problem. But is that what you're asking, or is this question really about automagically making all links change their ways, including in static html files?

Comment: I can do that but basically I want to have all paths relative to context not to the path in browser address. Eg: if I keep index.html in any sub folder, I don't want to change the paths inside the page. It should always fetch pages from context root of my application. Hence I want to know how can I set slash (/) as my application folder?

Comment: try using `href="./login"`

Answer (score 0):

By declaring a link `href="/login"` you make that an absolute link on your host. If you want login inside your app you'd have to prepend the context path (`request.getContextPath ()`) or use relative links ( `href="login"` )

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed context successfully in Tomcat and it is Start up successfully. Then the Application access directly the web.xml from the WEB-INF folder.

It access the servlet using the `<url-pattern>` and `<servlet-class>` to identify the servlet.

If you are worrying about accessing HTML files from the servlet you can access them directly from the context path.

i.e

if file present at `CONTEXT/html/file1.html` you can access it as `html/file1.html`

if file present at `CONTEXT/file2.html` you can access it as `file2.html`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `.` prefix to the `href` value.

`<a href="./login">` so that the URL will be `localhost:8080/testing1/login`